# Не обрабатывается нажатие ImageButton в libGDX

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

Никак не хочет обрабатываться нажатие кнопки. Подскажите, что я делаю не так ? Заранее спасибо.

```
private Stage stage2;
private ImageButton btnPlay;
private Texture btnT1;
private TextureRegion btnTR1;
private TextureRegionDrawable btnTRD1;

public MainMenu(final MyGame game) {
    this.game = game;

    stage2 = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage2);

    btnT1 = new Texture("startbutton.png");
    btnTR1 = new TextureRegion(btnT1);
    btnTRD1 = new TextureRegionDrawable(btnTR1);

    btnPlay = new ImageButton(btnTRD1);
    btnPlay.setPosition(400, 230);

    stage2.addActor(btnPlay);

    btnPlay.addListener(new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {
            if (true) game.setScreen(game.play);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage2.act();
    game.bat.begin();
    stage2.draw();
    game.bat.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `EventListener` следует использовать `ClickListener`.